# Less code for load and save methods in derived classes by using base class methods but without downcasting

Tags: c#, inheritance, clone

I'm trying to simplify load and save methods for several classes which are basically the base class with a few new fields. All derived classes make use of all base class' fields, so their load/save methods include the load/save code of the base class with an addition of some lines for taking care of the derived classes' remaining unhandled fields.

My first thought was I could just load an instance as a base class, downcast to derived class and continue loading the remaining fields, but apparently you can't just downcast to a derived class in C#. After some thinking I thought maybe I could iterate through all field members of the base class and copy over those field values to a new instance of derived class, but I'm not sure this is the best (or the fastest) way to do this.

Basically what I'd like to do is to load an instance of a base class, cast it to derived class, and then finish loading the remaining fields.

Is there some way to save the same lines of code in Load and Save methods of derived classes, which include all the Load and Save code from the base class without downcasting?

Here's some example code (the real thing is just a few times longer):

```
class Base 
{
    int i;
    static Base Load(Dictionary<string, object> dic)
    {
        Base b = new Base();
        b.i = (int)dic["i"];
        return b;
    }
}
class Derived : Base
{
    float f;
    static Derived Load(Dictionary<string, object> dic)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.i = (int)dic["i"];
        d.f = (float)dic["f"];
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to show your code so far..

Comment: So far I do exactly as described − derived classes' methods contain the base class' code plus some new lines to handle their own fields.

Comment: Is your question: how to call Load/Save method from base class when executing derived's Load/Save?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov my question is how to not call literally the same code of a base class in the derived class method, but somehow make use of the base class' methods and then be able finish the job.

Comment: @user1306322 Without code, all we can do is tell you that's impossible.  If you post code, it will make it a lot easier for us to help you find the right way to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I provided the wrong example code the first time. I really have static load methods, but save methods are non-static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for regular serialization code:

```
 class Base 
 {  
     public int Field1 {get;set;}
     virtual void Load(BinaryReader reader)
     {
         Field1 = reader.ReadInt();
     }
 }
 class Derived:Base
 {  
     public int Field2 {get;set;}
     override void Load(BinaryReader reader)
     {
         base.Load(reader);
         Field2 = reader.ReadInt();
     }
 }
```

With usage similar to:

```
 Base toRead = new Derived();
 toRead.Load(reader);
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something like this.

Comment: Wait, can I call the base method in a static Load method? Because I think I can't.

Comment: @user1306322 - normally you create *instance* of derived class and than call its Load/Read/Serialize instance method. Usually such methods are `virtual` so the only place where you need to know type is creation of the object (you have to know type at that point anyway somehow, i.e. by writing type to stream/having special property giving you Type).

Comment: @user1306322 or if you want to stick with `static` simply split creation and loading and call base class method `Load` from derived one.

Comment: This isn't necessary, I just changed it to non-static, like the Save methods, and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A cat and a dog is always an animal but an animal can be a cat or a dog. No way of of morphing a cat into a dog.

Comment: I'm trying to morph an animal into a cat (or a dog)